# Magento 2: Use custom connection for setup script

Tags: magento2

I have implemented multiple database for my Magento 2 website.

I have total three databases. magento, magento_checkout and magento_quote.   I have created my custom module which has custom flat table in setup script.  When this module runs, It is creating my table in magento database. I want it to be created in magento_checkout. I want to use connection of checkout database. I try to set argument in di.xml to use the connection of checkout database but it is using new connection for resource class but not working for setup class. My understanding says that if setup script will also use this new connection then my custom table will be created in magento_checkout. can someone help in this?

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_masterdb.html

https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/new-database-connection-in-magento-2